# can not set layout correctly when adding several uilabels to uitabelviewcell

Tags: ios, autolayout

I came across a problem when configuing the cell of UITableView. I add two labels vertically in the content view of the UITableViewCell, and I also add constraints for the top, leading and bottom layout attributes:

[image]

I think that the height of the cell can be caculated dynamically as I have set all the vertical layout and with the instrinct size of the label, the height can be inferred.

so, I can not understand the error message that IB told me.

The second problem is that the height of cell appear on the IB is not changed with the constraint I`ve make. If I decrease the bottom constraint for example, and it is the label to change its size to fit the constraint, but not the cell change its height.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add top , leading and trailing(or width) to the 1st label. Then add bottom ,leading and trailing(or width)for the bottom label. Then add bottom constraint for 1st label to 2nd label.Then by selecting both labels, add equal height constraint.It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of this conflict is that when your label content is increasing dynamically, which label's content is needed to give more priority before whom.

More precisely it can be said that if you increase one of the label's content hugging priority i.e. 252 then that label's content increment and size will be given more priority for incrementing it foremost. As autolayout executes according to the priority of constraints, it faces ambiguity in terms of increasing the views of labels if you do not set the content hugging priority.